# pragma omp parallel for and matrix definition

Tags: c++, matrix, parallel-processing, pragma, openmp

My problem is in the following code (win8 x64, visual studio):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>  
#define ARMA_USE_BLAS
#define ARMA_USE_LAPACK
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main() {
    int b_mean = 20;
    int b_max = 4 * b_mean;
    double p = 0.04265748215642;
    double F_bmax = 1 - pow((1 - p), (b_max + 1));
    double alpha = 0.1;

    vector<double> THR(EMAXRANGE + 1, 0);
    vector <vector <int> > q_finali(EMAXRANGE + 1, vector <int>(4, 0));

    const int MAX_E = 8;

    const int ORDINE = (int) pow((MAX_E + 1), 2);

    printf("EMAX=%d \n", MAX_E);
    const int etilde = (int) ceil((double) (MAX_E) / 2);

    //costruisco index
    vector <vector <int> > index(ORDINE, vector <int>(2, 0));
    int riga = 0;
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i <= MAX_E; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= MAX_E; j++) {
            index[riga][0] = i;
            index[riga][1] = j;
            //printf("i=%d, j=%d, riga=%d \n",i,j,riga);
            riga++;
        }

    }
    // costruisco Q
    vector <vector <int> > Q((2 * MAX_E) + 1, vector <int>(2, 0));
    Q[0][0] = 0; Q[0][1] = 0;
    riga = 1;
    for (j = 1; j <= MAX_E; j++) {
        Q[riga][0] = 0;
        Q[riga][1] = j;
        riga++;
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= MAX_E; i++) {
        Q[riga][0] = i;
        Q[riga][1] = 0;
        riga++;
    }

    int q_LL, q_LH, q_HL, q_HH;
    double G_max = 0;

    vector <vector <double> > P(ORDINE, vector <double>(ORDINE, 0));
    vector <double> g(ORDINE);

    int row;
    int tmp1;
    int tmp2;
    double rew;
    double temp;

#pragma omp parallel for
    for (q_HH = 1; q_HH <= (2 * MAX_E); q_HH++) {
        printf("q_HH=%d \n", q_HH);

        mat A = mat(ORDINE, ORDINE);

        /////// other things //////////
    }
}
```

All is working correctly, until the matrix definition, when an error occurs. This is my output:

```
 'Prova.exe' (Win32): caricamento di 'C:\Users\Davide\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Prova\Debug\Prova.exe' completato. Simboli caricati.
'Prova.exe' (Win32): caricamento di 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll' completato. Impossibile trovare o aprire il file PDB.
'Prova.exe' (Win32): caricamento di 'C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\snxhk.dll' completato. Impossibile trovare o aprire il file PDB.
'Prova.exe' (Win32): caricamento di 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll' completato. Impossibile trovare o aprire il file PDB.
'Prova.exe' (Win32): caricamento di 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll' completato. Impossibile trovare o aprire il file PDB.
'Prova.exe' (Win32): caricamento di 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp110d.dll' completato. Simboli caricati.
'Prova.exe' (Win32): caricamento di 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110d.dll' completato. Simboli caricati.
'Prova.exe' (Win32): caricamento di 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcomp110d.dll' completato. Simboli caricati.
'Prova.exe' (Win32): caricamento di 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll' completato. Impossibile trovare o aprire il file PDB.
'Prova.exe' (Win32): caricamento di 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll' completato. Impossibile trovare o aprire il file PDB.
'Prova.exe' (Win32): caricamento di 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll' completato. Impossibile trovare o aprire il file PDB.
'Prova.exe' (Win32): caricamento di 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll' completato. Impossibile trovare o aprire il file PDB.
'Prova.exe' (Win32): caricamento di 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll' completato. Impossibile trovare o aprire il file PDB.
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCP110D.dll
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\vector
Line: 1140

Expression: vector subscript out of range

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)
Second Chance Assertion Failed: File c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\vector, Line 1140
Prova.exe ha avviato un punto di interruzione.
```

I think it is something caused by the matrix definition, as if I comment that line all runs smoothly.

Here it is a translation of the error message:

```
     'Prova.exe' (Win32): loading of 'C:\Users\Davide\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Prova\Debug\Prova.exe' completed. Symbols loaded.
'Prova.exe' (Win32): loading of 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll' completed. Impossible to find or open the PDB file.
'Prova.exe' (Win32): loading of 'C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\snxhk.dll' completed. Impossible to find or open the PDB file.
'Prova.exe' (Win32): loading of 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll' completed. Impossible to find or open the PDB file.
'Prova.exe' (Win32): loading of 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll' completed. Impossible to find or open the PDB file.
'Prova.exe' (Win32): loading of 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp110d.dll' completed. Symbols loaded.
'Prova.exe' (Win32): loading of 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110d.dll' completed. Symbols loaded.
'Prova.exe' (Win32): loading of 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcomp110d.dll' completato. Symbols loaeded.
'Prova.exe' (Win32): loading of 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll' completed. Impossible to find or open the PDB file.
'Prova.exe' (Win32): loading of 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll' completed. Impossible to find or open the PDB file.
'Prova.exe' (Win32): loading of 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll' completed. Impossible to find or open the PDB file.
'Prova.exe' (Win32): loading of 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll' completed. Impossible to find or open the PDB file.
'Prova.exe' (Win32): loading of 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll' completed. Impossible to find or open the PDB file.
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCP110D.dll
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\vector
Line: 1140

Expression: vector subscript out of range

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)
Second Chance Assertion Failed: File c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\vector, Line 1140
Prova.exe has run an interruption point.
```

Comment: It might be helpful to translate the error messages into English for those of us who don't read Italian or whatever it is...

Comment: Done! Thank you if you'll try to help me

Comment: Did you read the error message? `Expression: vector subscript out of range`. Fix that.

Comment: What is `EMAXRANGE` defined as? The other constants you use for sizing your vectors seem well defined (if a bit oddly...) - `MAX_E == 8`, `ORDINE == 64`. You do realize array indexing of `array[N]` goes from `0` to `N-1`, right? I see a bunch of `<=` in loop termination conditions, which is suspect, but you also size your arrays as `N+1` for the most part, so maybe that's ok; but if you missed one somewhere, that could easily be the problem...

Comment: EMAXRANGE is defined as:
#define EMAXRANGE 20

The fact is i don't understand why error "Expression: vector subscript out of range" is thrown as it comes only with the initialization of the matrix, and only if the pragma omp.. command is used. if i run this program without the pragma command no error is thrown